# iOS beta app is no longer available

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

This is the current status of the beta app:

[image]

I received a notification of mine ***seconds*** ago, but cannot go to the app. After I read it on the web, the notification *disappeared*. I think this is a bug.

I send this bug on the official app on Apple Store.

- App Version: 1.4.0
- Device: iPad2,2
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: Noti? It's not a pet

Comment: (aka please use whole words)

Comment: @sha: why not? It has been accepted as an abbreviation

Comment: Where exactly??

Comment: @Sha googling [`noti define`](https://www.google.com/search?q=noti+define&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: What about it? There is no official term. If you mean [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=NOTI&defid=5490224), it can't be more far away than "accepted as an abbreviation". This is pure slang, and bad one too. U  cen sem wy uz ani zleng u vant. (aka it's just bad English)

Comment: of course not the urban. Doesn't Google give you the definition box of Merriam - Webster? Or do you think that one shallow does not make a summer?

Comment: Yes but it's just because Google is smart enough to auto suggest the full word, it does not mean "noti" is official abbreviation

Comment: Ah ok. Because I saw it written as "full definition of Notification" in the WM dictionary, so I thought it was already a abbreviation. When going to the dictionary itself and search for "noti", there is no result.

Comment: True. Glad I was finally able to persuade you. :-)

Comment: You win, yay :D. Next time I will still use *noti*, but have a footnote that it's *notification* xD

Comment: Fair enough. Thinking about it, it's more funny than irritating. :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed-ish. The new build will work but you if you don't have a working app or the link to download it, you can't get the new version. That's pretty problematic since the only way some people could get it to work is for me to email out the link and I don't want to send the link to the whole beta tester pool considering how few of the testers are still active. I'm going to start evaluating Test Flight as a new distribution channel next week.

So what happened? The provisioning profile used to sign the apps expired. This produced the "no longer available" message on run and the failure to install on download. I expected an expired certificate to break a download but not break an installed app.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this has been fixed now. When clicking on the icon again it downloads the app and installs correctly.

Comment: ugh, how can it download the app without be able to open it?

Comment: If you tap the grayed out icon you can. You can also go to the original download location.

Comment: It seems like some people are in a state where they were downloading the updated app and can tap to redownload.  Others are in a state where they can still tap the app to launch it and that instantly fails.  @Ooker, I'm gonna email you a link.

Comment: Does removing and reinstalling from the usual place work?. @brian

Comment: Just going to the link should cause it to reinstall without deleting.  The problem is that we don't publish the link so people either need to search their email or we need to send out a bulk message to 1000 people who might not still be testing.

Comment: I'm going to evaluate Test Flight after the holiday.

Comment: @BrianNickel I'm here on the beta app. So is this the correct answer that I should accept?

Comment: Does it work for you now?

Comment: @PatrickHofman it works. I just want to know *why* it broke, but if it is hard to have an answer, but I'm fine to accept this.

Comment: No problem. I just was curious if it worked for you.

Comment: @BrianNickel - Am I missing something? I don't see a link for downloading the iOS-app? If I'm not missing anything, how do I go about getting it? I'm getting the crash on opening ... I know I need to reinstall, I just don't know how to get it (or get to the URL for download).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is related, but it was crashing on startup for me for me starting yesterday. After finding this question, I redownloaded the latest beta and it's working now.

Good thing I never delete my email...

Comment: how does this improve or add more info to the existing answers?

Comment: @Ooker: I believe, but have no proof that this was a different symptom for the same problem, which can be fixed in the same way -- download and install the latest version.