# App instantly crashes on startup

Tags: bug, ios-app

The iOS beta app instantly crashes when starting it.

I am running iOS 9.1 with version 1.4.0.247 of the app.

It might be related to [iOS beta app is no longer available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269981/245360) since that issue happens around the same time.

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: The other question has been fixed and now the application works correctly. I guess he two were related after all.